# How to create a NativeView in Nativescript-Angular?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I'm developing a mobile App with Nativescript and Angular, but I've a problem to create an *headerView* to add inside the **CFAlertDialog** (I'm using the plugin *nativescript-cfalert-dialog*).

I created a service to inject to several components in my app, which is something like this

```
import * as application from 'tns-core-modules/application'

@Injectable()
export class PlayerDialogService {
...
    constructor() {
        const context = application.android.context as android.content.Context;
        this.generateAndroidNativeView(context)

    }

    private generateAndroidNativeView(context: android.content.Context) {
        this.usernameLabel = new android.widget.TextView(context)
        this.usernameLabel.setTextSize(20)

        this.fullNameLabel = new android.widget.TextView(context)
        this.fullNameLabel.setTextSize(16)

        this.playerImage = new android.widget.ImageView(context)
        this.playerImage.setMaxWidth(48)
        this.playerImage.setMaxHeight(48)

        this.textStackLayout = new android.widget.LinearLayout(context)
        this.textStackLayout.addView(this.usernameLabel)
        this.textStackLayout.addView(this.fullNameLabel)

        this.stackLayout = new android.widget.LinearLayout(context)
        this.stackLayout.addView(this.playerImage)
        this.stackLayout.addView(this.textStackLayout)
    }
}
```

Fact is that everytime the dialog is loaded (I open a component/view that has the `PlayerDialogService` injected), I get this error:

`JS: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'usernameLabel' of undefined`

I'm afraid I'm not passing the correct Context (despite it's not an empty object, nor an undefined one), but has a constructor included. So... what am I missing?

Comment: May I ask, why you would want to create UI elements natively? Why not use TextField and Label from tns core modules. Besides Yes, you are not passing correct context. You are passing the class but you suppose to pass the context instance that can be found in application module (`application.android.context` where `application` is imported from `tns-core-modules/application` - [docs](https://docs.nativescript.org/ns-framework-modules/application)).

Comment: The plugin allows to create a customized alert dialog where pass several properties, including an headerView and a footerView. Unfortunately, these two must be nativeView objects, so I can't use Labels, which are waaaaay more easier.

About the context, I still not understand where to get the context instance. I red the docs, but I guess I'm gonna read them again to try to understand what I'm missing.

Comment: Sorry my bad, when I saw the term `stackLayout` I presumed it was `StackLayout` from core package. I might not have noticed it's instance of `LinearLayout`. But still, all underlaying components are native, you could create {N} components (TextField, Label, StackLayout etc.,) and pass in the native view. You might have to call the private methods like setupUI on parent view before passing it to the plugin.

Comment: For context try, `import * as application from "tns-core-modules/application"; this.generateAndroidNativeView(application.android.context);`

Comment: You're suggestion seems good as mine, but is there any difference from the code I wrote up there?